# var output = 1 + 2 + 3 + "4" + 5 + "90"; Output : 64590;; Just want to know why?

Tags: c#

Need to know the logical reason behind the stated output

```
var output = 1 + 2 + 3 + "4" + 5 + "90";
```

Output : "64590"

Comment: `1 + 2 + 3` is `6`. `6 + "4"` is `"64"`. `"64" + 5` is `"645"`. `"645" + "90"` is `"64590"`. `int + int` is an `int`, but `anything + string` is a `string`.

Comment: Because there are strings in there, the compiler assumes you want to stringify everything. It may be mistaken, but the compiler can't learn from experience and you can.

Comment: #DataTypesMatter

Comment: In addition to canton7's comment, when concatenating `anything` with some `string` (`anything + string`), then _anything_ -- unless it is already a string or can be implicitly converted to a string -- will be first transformed into a string by invoking its _ToString()_ method; think of it like `anything.ToString() + string` (or rather `anything?.ToString() + string` if _anything_ happens to be a reference type)

Answer (score 7):

Because expressions are evaluated from left to right, and all of the operators in this expression have the same order of precedence.  So let's take them one at a time...

```
1 + 2 = 3
3 + 3 = 6
6 + "4" = "64"
"64" + 5 = "645"
"645" + "90" = "64590"
```

- When you use `+` on two integers the result is an integer, summing the two
- When you use `+` on two strings the result is a string, concatenating the two
- When you use `+` on a string and an integer (or anything, I suspect) the result is a string, implicitly converting the integer to a string (likely by invoking `.ToString()` on it in the compiled code) and then concatenating the two

Any time the result of a multi-part expression is unexpected, a good debugging step is to split it into individual operations and store the results in observable variables.  Then step through each operation in a debugger and observe the result of each.  If a *specific* operation produces an unexpected result, your next step is to identify what result you expected and *why*.

Answer (score 5):

The `+` operator has several overloads. Relevant for your piece of code are

```
// Integer addition
int operator +(int x, int y); // A

// String concatenation
string operator +(string x, string y); // B
string operator +(string x, object y); // C
string operator +(object x, string y); // D
```

For cases C and B, note the relevant part of the C# 6.0 specification (§7.8.4 Addition operator)

> These overloads of the binary + operator perform string concatenation.
>   If an operand of string concatenation is null, an empty string is
>   substituted. Otherwise, any non-string argument is converted to its
>   string representation by invoking the virtual ToString method
>   inherited from type object. If ToString returns null, an empty string
>   is substituted.

Thus, your expression

```
var output = 1 + 2 + 3 + "4" + 5 + "90";
```

is evaluated left to right with the operators used as follows:

```
var output = ((((1 + 2) + 3) + "4") + 5) + "90";
                 --A--
                 -----A-----
                 ---------D--------
                 ------------C----------
                 ------------------B-----------
```

Answer (score 1):

when you input a value without declaring its type then its type is decided implicitly, So, here 1 2 3 are integers and gives the arithmetic sum 6. And the next "4" is a string so it is being concatenated  and next 5 is an integer which is also being concatenated ,Which might be confusing.

So here your question should be why string + integers or integers + strings are concatenated, that`s because, in real world there is no result of "ab" + 2 or 3 + "laila" or "hi" + 5 etc , that`s why here compiler assumes that you are not intentionally trying to add alphabets with integers you are trying to concatenate them.So , compiler implicitly does this for your ease.

Answer (score 0):

Because 1,2,3, and 5 are integers while "4" and "9" are strings. 1+2+3 = 6. 6 + "4" = 64 (it's being concatenated, the + operator doesn't JUST do math additions, it also concatenates. eg.

```
string concat = "dog" + "cat"; //
 //concat will now be assigned with "dogcat"
```

Moving forward, "4" + 5 will come out to 45.. so right now we have 645 and add a "90" in there and it will be 64590